# Regex to match string starting with particular number and ending in semicolon

Tags: java, regex

I have some string with pattern:

```
15764_Coordinator/Principal Investigator, Curator;44504_Database Manager, Architect;43401_Scientific Expert;43701_Scientific Expert;
```

The delimiter in this pattern is a semicolon `;`. Provided that I have any starting number say `44504`, I want to delete the string part starting with this number up until the semicolon `;`. The string after deleting will be:

```
15764_Coordinator/Principal Investigator, Curator;43401_Scientific Expert;43701_Scientific Expert;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: a regex would be useful if you were trying to find all strings that match a pattern; but you are trying to find just one string out of N; so probably easier to search for it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to to use `string.replaceAll` function.

```
string.replaceAll("(?m)(?<=^|;)44504[^;]*;", "")
```

- `(?m)`  Multiline modifier. It's necessary when you're dealing with multi-line input where your regex contain anchors (*`^`, `$`*)
- `(?<=^|;)` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a semi-colon or start of the line.
- `[^;]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `;`, zero or more times.

**Example:**

```
String s = "15764_Coordinator/Principal Investigator, Curator;44504_Database Manager, Architect;43401_Scientific Expert;43701_Scientific Expert;";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=^|;)44504[^;]*;", ""));
```

Output:

```
15764_Coordinator/Principal Investigator, Curator;43401_Scientific Expert;43701_Scientific Expert;
```

Comment: positions.replaceAll("(?m)(?<=^|;)"+organizationid+"[^;]*;", "");
System.out.println(positions);
It is printing the same string after replaceAll.

Comment: you need to assign the result back to another variable `String s = positions.replaceAll("(?m)(?<=^|;)"+organizationid+"[^;]*;", ""); System.out.println(s);` because strings are immutable in java.

Comment: Perfect! Works like advertised.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
string.replaceAll("(?<=\;)44504.*?\;", "")
```

Comment: but it would do the replacement on  `foo44504nmbar`

Comment: Sorry, I dont know it works for java or not but it works for PHP like preg_replace('/44504.*?\;/', '', $string);

Comment: yep, it works for current input. But what if the input is like `foobar;foo44504nmbar;` . In this case your regex will remove this `44504nmbar;` part. BUt op want to remove the whole part where the `44504` substring appears at the very first that is, just after to a semicolon or at the start. It's not language specific.

Comment: you are correct, I need to include look behind condition before numbers. Thanks..